# error while 'making' fontforge from source

Tags: compiler-errors, makefile, cygwin, fontforge

I use cygwin to compile fontforge.
I was able to configure it, but when I try to 'make' I got this nasty error message:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 Makefile:91: recipe for target '../libfontforge.la' failed
  make[1]: *** [../libfontforge.la] Error 1
  make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/cygwin/fontforge-20120731/fontforge'
  Makefile:28: recipe for target 'fontforge' failed
  make: *** [fontforge] Error 2
```

does anyone knows what is the solution for that?

Comment: This tells us nothing about the error itself, other than it's a linker error, `make V=0` should be able to tell you more.

Comment: The lines directly *before* this are the relevant ones. And you want `V=1` to turn on verbose output (`V=0` is silent rules) but I don't know that I think that's relevant here at the moment.

Comment: okay here is the full log, when I try to 'make' (with v=1)
http://codebeautify.org/alleditor/dd3fa6 
thanks @ user657267 @ Etan Reisner

Answer (score 0):

Fontforge requires a number of patches in order to build.  The [Cygwin Ports](http://cygwinports.org/) repository includes a fontforge package which you can install with Cygwin Setup, or you can see how the package is built for Cygwin in [Ports git](https://sourceforge.net/p/cygwin-ports/fontforge/).